# Guava NoClassDefFound for one call only on Android

Tags: android, guava

I'm using Google guava in Android and everything is working fine. Except for one method (or set of methods).

When I call

Files.write(.......)

to send a byte array to a file I get this:

02-02 23:57:57.528: E/AndroidRuntime(11892): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.util.ArrayDeque

This is the line I think:
02-02 23:57:57.528: E/AndroidRuntime(11892):    at com.google.common.io.Closer.(Closer.java:110)

Guava is working, normal file IO is working,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess your Android has Java 5 and `ArrayDeque` exists `@Since` 6. So everything works except when Guava uses something not existing in Java 5.

You need a [Guava backport to JDK5](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/guava-discuss/RiiMam7VvSc/omv4uYG5SFYJ).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, now sorted :)

Not really related, but following your link, I've tried at various times to write to the Android Developers group but I never get a reply , so I guess the moderators must be permanently on holiday ;)

Comment: @Neil: I guess there are too many (often clueless) people trying to program Android and they're simply overwhelmed.